# I need help to separate my .dat file by lines of odd numbers in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I've this .dat (`EvsKpoint_Sn.dat`) file with 30 lines and I need to separate the odd-numbered lines into a different file.

I've made the code below but it's not working as I expected.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(seq 1 2 29)
do
        sed -n '$ip' EvsKpoint_Sn.dat >> EvsKsep.dat    
done
```

It is returning only a lot of "p" in the output file.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need use double quotes `"` with sed to expand shell variable, and since `ip` are together, you need to use `{}` to separate the varible with other thing.

I.E.

```
sed -n "${i}p"
```

Second, sed can do this task all by itself:

```
sed 'n;d' file
```

Try this, see if it's what you want:

```
sed 'n;d' EvsKpoint_Sn.dat >> EvsKsep.dat
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an Awk attempt.

```
awk 'NR%2' EvsKpoint_Sn.dat > EvsKsep.dat
```

The variable `NR` is the input line number and `%` is the familiar modulo operation. So if the line number divided by 2 leaves a reminder, we print it.

Running a `sed` script on the same file repeatedly in a loop is an antipattern. The usual solution is to generate a script with the operations you want to perform, then pass it to `sed` and let it process the input file just once.

```
seq 1 2 29 |
sed 's/$/p/' |
sed -n -f - EvsKpoint_Sn.dat > EvsKsep.dat
```

However, this is not entirely portable.  Linux `sed` is happy to read the script on standard input, but some other versions won't.